# consume nested data in d3/javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

sI am currently working on a project in d3 in which I created a nested json object from a csv file (see code snippet) It has multiple keys and a arry of values which I want to plot on a map.

```
0:
   key: "Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant (ISIL)"
      values:
         kills: 30889
         map_data:
            Array(4287)
               [0 … 99]
                  0: {longitude: "44.290423", latitude: "33.297678", nkill: "28", nwound: "50", city: "Baghdad", …}
                  1: {longitude: "44.356585", latitude: "32.985052", nkill: "0", nwound: "4", city: "Latifiyah", …}
1:
   key: "Taliban"
      values:
         kills: 24482
         map_data: 
            Array(6575)
               [0 … 99]
                  0: {longitude: "", latitude: "", nkill: "0", nwound: "0", city: "Unknown", …}
                  1: {longitude: "65.675942", latitude: "31.617667", nkill: "0", nwound: "0", city: "Kandahar", …}
```

[edit] I want to project a circle for each item in the map_data array but the circle attributes only take one value which as said in the comment by Shashank. Is there an other way to get my correct data inside the attribute?

```
g.selectAll("circle")
.data(topgroups)
.enter()
.append("a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return "https://www.google.com/search?q="+d.key;}
)
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) {
    d.values.map_data.map(function (t) {
        return projection([t.Longitude, t.Latitude])[0];
    })
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
    d.values.map_data.map(function (t) {
        return projection([t.Longitude, t.Latitude])[1];
    })
})
.attr("r", function(d) {
    d.values.map_data.map(function (t) {
        return t.nkill/500;
    })
})
.style("fill", "red");
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back with the edits. So [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle#Example)'s how attributes are defined for a circle. In your case, `cx, cy and r` are being assigned an array by doing `d.values.map_data.map()` which wouldn't work. Could you clarify me on this: as the `map_data` in the screenshot is an `Array` of **4287** elements, are you trying to add **4287** circles positioned at `projection([longitude, latitude)[0]` ?

Comment: i am trying to project a circle for each item in the map_data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for getting back with the exact requirement and some more code. Here's the thing:

You are trying to **bind** an object whereas you always have to bind an **array** to a selection in D3.

And as you need circles for each item in the `map_data` array, you have to bind this array to `d3.selectAll('circle')`

Check out [this link](https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements) to understand more about data-binding in D3.

Here's a code snippet that does the above and appends circles to the SVG along with attributes `cx`, `cy` and `r` assigned as per your initial requirement i.e. calling `projection` etc.

***It includes a sample array similar to yours BUT please make sure you provide a code snippet of the data rather than a screenshot***

```js
var topgroups = {
 key: 'ISIL',
  values: {
   kills: 30899,
    map_data: [
     {
      city: "A",
       latitude: '20',
       longitude: '40',
        nkill: 100
       },
       {
        city: "B",
        latitude: '90',
        longitude: '50',
        nkill: 200
       },
       {
        city: "C",
        latitude: '120',
        longitude: '140',
        nkill: 300
       },
       {
        city: "D",
        latitude: '120',
        longitude: '250',
        nkill: 400
       }
    ]
  }
};

function projection(lt, long) {
 return [lt, long];
}

d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('width', 400).attr('height', 350)
  .append('g').attr('class', 'circles');
  
  
var circles = d3.select('svg g.circles').selectAll('circle')  
        .data(topgroups.values.map_data);
                
   circles.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return projection(+d.latitude, +d.longitude)[0];   
    }).attr('cy', function(d) {
     return projection(+d.latitude, +d.longitude)[1];
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
     return d.nkill/40;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** 
 Initially in the image, it was shown as an object and hence the above code. Anyway, I thought you would take it from there if it was an array. It's simple ***enter/update/exit*** pattern.

Here's a snippet doing that:

```js
var topgroups = [
{
 key: 'ISIL',
  values: {
   kills: 30899,
    map_data: [
     {
      city: "A",
       latitude: '20',
       longitude: '40',
        nkill: 100
       },
       {
        city: "B",
        latitude: '90',
        longitude: '50',
        nkill: 200
       },
       {
        city: "C",
        latitude: '120',
        longitude: '140',
        nkill: 300
       },
       {
        city: "D",
        latitude: '120',
        longitude: '250',
        nkill: 400
       }
    ]
  }
},
{
 key: 'ISIL2',
  values: {
   kills: 308990,
    map_data: [
     {
      city: "E",
       latitude: '100',
       longitude: '40',
        nkill: 100
       },
       {
        city: "F",
        latitude: '10',
        longitude: '120',
        nkill: 200
       }
    ]
  }
}
];

function projection(lt, long) {
 return [lt, long];
}

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('width', 400).attr('height', 350);
  
  var g = svg.selectAll('g.circles').data(topgroups);
   g.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'circles').attr('data-key', function(d) { return d.key; });
  
  
var circles = d3.selectAll('svg g.circles').selectAll('circle')  
                .data(function(d) { 
                 return d.values.map_data; 
                });
                
   circles.enter().append('circle')
     .attr('cx', function(d) {
       return projection(+d.latitude, +d.longitude)[0];   
    }).attr('cy', function(d) {
      return projection(+d.latitude, +d.longitude)[1];
    })
     .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.nkill/40;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: well I can access the data this way but the attribute does not want to show the data

Comment: Oh my bad too! I didn't look up the attribute. A `cx` attribute requires just 1 value but in this case you are returning an array which would definitely not work. It'd be nice if you could provide more code, data.

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer I hope that this provides you enough information to help me

Comment: The answer you provided is not fully working because I have more then one key so it also needs to loop through all the keys and then it needs to loop through map_data array for each key. I also added a code snipped of my data to the question like you asked. I hope that it is enough to get it working now

Comment: Sorry for getting back pretty late. Check out the latest edit and the new code snippet.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.